# Use save() within sfClusterCall()

Tags: r, snowfall

I want to run a parallelized simulation using `snowfall`. Trying to aquire data using `return()` causes the cluster to exceed memory limitations. Data is at some point not recorded anymore.
So I want to use `save()` to write the data to a file after each replicate.

> sfInit()
>
> try<-function(x){
>
> save(list=ls(),file=paste("myfilename_",x,".RData",sep=""))
>
> }
>
> sfClusterSetupRNG()
>
> sfClusterCall(try,1:100)
>
> sfStop()

The error I get is

> Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : invalid 'description' argument
>
> Calls: sfClusterCall -> do.call ->  -> save -> gzfile
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In if (!nzchar(file)) stop("'file' must be non-empty string") :
>
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used